# how to do while with promise?

Tags: javascript, q

i have logic with promise with while it do promsie with name if it found it I want that the promise will call again with new name ( name + index)
The problem after the first promise it called it didn't continue to the next while and return from the function.
What is wring ?

```
       var result = true;
       var that = this;
       var name = "testFoler";
       while (result) {
            var index = 0;
            return that.context.doPromise(name).then(function(promiseResult) {
                if (promiseResult === null){
                    return Q(name)
                } else {
                    index++;
                    name = name + index
                }
            });

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are passing "reuslt" as parameter which certainly does not exist.

Comment: That's irrelevant, OP has an actual issue.

Comment: it's certainly relevant.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I fixed it result it just fro the loop

Comment: @Andy a typo is irrelevant

Comment: How about if the typo is causing an error that is preventing the code from going any further?

Comment: @Andy they are right there is a problem with the promise. So it wasn't the main issue. Sorry for the hasty answer.

Comment: what is the problem? how I can fix it ?